# When creating a meeting in Microsoft Teams, can one configure it so that it starts recording automatically from the beginning of the meeting?

Tags: recording, microsoft-teams, conferencing

When creating a meeting in Microsoft Teams, can one configure it so that it starts recording automatically from the beginning of the meeting (e.g., to avoid forgetting to record it)?

I use Microsoft Teams on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the date this question has been asked, no.

But, it's coming.

> Microsoft Teams recording
> The new feature has apparently been in the works for a while, with Microsoft confirming the news in response to a query on the company's [UserVoice forum](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/35515465-automatic-recording-meetings), noting that it was "currently working on this request" and would, “will share an update as soon as one is available”.